Detecting if there an element or iframe overlaid on top of my iframe to prevent clickjacking
Detecting if there an element or iframe overlaid on top of my iframe
I have an iframe that can be embedded inside any website based on the content security policy.
Is there a way for the my iframe code to detect if there is an element or iframe laid on top of it to prevent clickjacking?
I tried using the trackVisibility in the IntersectionObserver v2 API for this purpose. Let us assume for now that we are good with the fact that support on Chrome is good enough.
For simplicity of discussion, let us assume that the threshold is set to 1.0, so that the entire iframe has to be visible for isVisible to be true. Also, let us call my iframe as iframeGood and the overlaid malicious iframe to be iframeBad.
If the opacity of iframeBad is set to anything higher than 0, then the isVisible of the IntersectionObserver API shows the value as false.
However, if the opacity of the iframeBad is set to 0, then the isVisible of the IntersectionObserver API shows the value as true. Maybe this is intended since iframeGood is fully visible in this case, but it does not solve of the problem of clickjacking.
So is there a way to detecting if there an element or iframe overlaid on top of my iframe from within my iframe?

Impossible, you have no control on the parent website embedding your site in a frame. That is, unless you also own it and can load code into it.

Also, there is no clickjacking: if you're letting people embed your content in frames, then you are not in control. Not just in the "you don't control the parent" but in the "you gave up control when you decided that your content could be embedded": you already acknowledge that folks can do whatever browser-legal things they want with your embed. Pages with your embed can do anything and everything they want, short of "reaching into the iframe" (because that's locked down by the browser's security model), so serve content accordingly.

Similarly, your embedded content has zero rights to (or even knowledge of) the parent page by default: it would be a security nightmare if that was allowed. You can make this happen by configuring your own server as well as the server that hosts the parent page to agree to allow mutual access, but that's basically asking someone to bake potential exploits into their pages.  Asking embedders to load some JS that you wrote that talks to your iframe via postMessage is realistically your only option (where your iframe's blank unless that JS gets loaded or something).

This is not possible from the iframe, but if you where to supply your clients with some JS that loads your iframe, then this could also use the InteresectionObserver API to test if another page element intersects your iframe. However you would then have to apply it to every element on the page and most likely use the MutationObserver API to check for elements being added late to the page as well.
This can all be done without adding any real overhead to the parent page, as these are pretty low level API that don’t really effect page performance, so long as you use them in an intelligent way.
Code would look roughly something like this
function coverObserver(options) {
  const onChange = options.onChange || (() => {})

  const observerOptions = {
    root: options.root,
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 0,
  }

  function callback(entries) {
    onChange(entries.map((entry) => entry.target))
  }

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, observerOptions)
  const observed = new WeakSet()

  return function (nodeList) {
    for (const node of nodeList) {
      if (node.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE || observed.has(node)) continue

      observer.observe(node)
      observed.add(node)
    }
  }
}

coverObsever({
  root: myIframe,
  onChange: (coveringNodeList) => 
    console.log('Iframe covered by', ...coveringNodeList),
})(
  document.querySelectorAll('* :not(iframe)')
)

